Height of a pyramid formed from a random triangle
I have drawn a height (brown) from the orthocenter of the triangle, this height is perpendicular to both side edges, is it possible to relate this height to a,b and c? if possible, what is the formula?
summation of three equations
$x^2+y^2+z^2=\frac{a^2+b^2+c^2}{2}\Rightarrow x=\sqrt{\frac{a^2-b^2+c^2}{2}}, y=\sqrt{\frac{a^2+b^2-c^2}{2}}, z=\sqrt{\frac{-a^2+b^2-c^2}{2}} $
$h=?$ (brown)


Just to check, the yellow, purple etc edges are perpendicular to eachother? If so, yes there is a formula as you can take their intersection as the origin and the triangle as a plane, then use the distance from point to a plane formula. I'll add a proper answer later unless someone beats me to it.

It can be shown (by calculating the area of the pyramid in two different ways) that $\frac{1}{h}=\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{y}+\frac{1}{z}$
(Alternatively, take the intersection of the purple, yellow and pink lines as the point $(0,0,0)$ and the triangle as a plane intersecting the axes at $(x,0,0),(0,y,0),(0,0,z)$ and use the distance from point to plane formula)
Then (using your expressions for $x,y,z$ in terms of $a,b,c$) we can write:
$\frac{1}{h}=\sqrt{\frac{2}{a^2-b^2+c^2}}+\sqrt{\frac{2}{a^2+b^2-c^2}}+\sqrt{\frac{2}{-a^2+b^2+c^2}}$
Which can be rearranged to give an equation for $h$ but I think it looks better in this form.
